# How to make list of items scrollable inside grid

Tags: reactjs, scroll, flexbox, css-grid, tailwind-css

I'm working on a simple to-do list app with tailwind, I'm stuck on making the task list scrollable inside its grid container, currently it's pushing down the bottom modal I have for creating new tasks. I've created a stack blitz demo with some pretty similar styling: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-hq5up7?file=src/App.tsx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you give it maximum height and set overflow-Y to (auto or scroll)

```
max-height: 'whatever you want',
overflow-Y: 'auto or scroll',
```

I suggest you use overflow auto. Because if it is not overflowing. It won't show you an ugly scrollbar.
Here, I resolved it in your demo.
[Resolved Demo Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-pfwtje?file=src/App.tsx)

Comment: I was playing around with max-h but couldn't find a good value inside tailwind, I thought there could have been a trick with flex-grow, thank you so much!